# Needs clarification about Nmap and OpenSSL results

Tags: ssl, openssl, nmap

I have configured the below cipher list in Apache's ssl.conf file. And my application is running on RHEL 8.5 OS with OpenSSL version 1.1.1k.

```
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-CCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
```

I'm running the below Nmap command to test the strength of the cipher suites which I used in my application,

`nmap -sV --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 8443 <IP_ADDRESS>`

Please find the below output snippet.

```
 TLSv1.2:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: client
|_  least strength: A
```

And I knew that the certificates which I used in the application are signed with RSA. so it displays the ciphers which are having RSA authentication.

Also, When I try to execute the below command, I got "*error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure:ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1544:SSL alert number 40*" error.

> openssl s_client -connect XX.XX.XX.XX:8443 -cipher ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305

My queries,

1. Why "ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305 and DHE-RSA-AES256-CCM" are not displayed by Nmap command even though they have RSA authentication?
2. Why the handshake failure happened with that cipher?

Thanks.

Comment: Please create a minimal server config which only includes this specific port, test with this config and if the problem continues provide this whole config. It is unclear if the sslciphersuite setting you show is even applied for your port 8443.

Comment: What does the output from `nmap` look like if you add one or more `-v` (verbose) options, such as `nmap -vvvvv -sV --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 8443 <IP_ADDRESS>`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle. I got the same result(Only 2 ciphers) as above.<


|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A

Comment: Does `openssl ciphers -v` on your web server list all the ciphers in your configuration?  If it does, where is your Apache process getting its OpenSSL libraries from?  You can check in `/proc/PID/maps`, wher `PID` is the process ID of the Apache web server process.  If all that checks out, get a copy of `ssl-cipher-suite-enum.pl` from https://labs.portcullis.co.uk/tools/ssl-cipher-suite-enum/ and run it against your server and see what it says is supported.